# IF statement that is greater than and less than specific numbers

Tags: java, if-statement, int

I have a project where I have to create a tax application. I have two integers: gross and taxrate. When the user inputs his gross income, I want it to multiply the certain percentage of the tax rate in his bracket for the tax due. My code is the following:

```
if (gross < 9075) {
    taxrate = (int) (gross * .10);
}
else (gross > 9075 && < 36900) {
    taxrate = (int) (gross * .15);
}
```

It tells me there is an error, so I assume I am messing up somewhere. Is there a way to create a proper if statement that goes between two numbers?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the C-like languages have a mechanism for testing "between" in a single operation, so you must code two separate compare expressions -- `gross > 9075 && gross < 36900`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must explicitly state both operands to any binary operator, including comparison operators.  Try

```
} else if (gross > 9075 && gross < 36900) {
```

Incidentally you may need to consider the case of exactly `9075`, either with

```
if (gross <= 9075){
```

OR

```
} else if (gross >= 9075 && < 36900) {
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it was that easy. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @ZouZou Yes, I missed the secondary error.  Fixed now.

Comment: @ZouZou Ugh.  Fixed again.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, but do you know of a way to make the taxrate integer usable in other pieces of code? it shows "0" in the program once its called.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a conditional with the else statement, and not using your operators correctly. You want to change this to

```
else if (gross > 9075 && gross < 36900)
```

Notice I have changed `else` to `else if` and changed the conditional to have the comparisons done correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving it as

```
taxrate = (int) (gross*0.10f);
```

and

```
 taxrate = (int) (gross*0.15f);
```

Comment: You may want to expand your answer :)

Comment: I think you are trying to suggest that he use floating point values for tax rate...? Could you expand on this answer maybe?